# Display a page with extended information

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have the following functionality given below:
[image]

When clicking on details, i want the text that is displayed on the contentview shall be displayed on the new detailspage that is created by push async. How can I send parameters containing the info given in the content, e.g. title, category and description.

I have a tap gesture recognizer:

```
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
     <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
</Label.GestureRecognizers>
```

That then leads to creating a new page with the code behind:

```
private async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage(user), true);
    }
```

So how shall I bind the labels containing title, description and category to display in the new page that is created upon click?

Here's the xaml code behind the labels:

```
                        <StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <BoxView Color="LightGray"
                                     WidthRequest="90"
                                     HeightRequest="90"
                                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                     VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                <StackLayout Padding="0">

                                    <Label x:Name="Title" Text="Title"
                                       FontSize="22"
                                       FontFamily="Grotesk"
                                       TextColor="Black"
                                       Margin="10, -2, 0, 0"
                                       VerticalOptions="Fill" />
                                    <Label x:Name="Category" Text="Category"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       FontFamily="Grotesk"
                                       TextColor="Gray"
                                       Margin="10, -2, 0, 0"
                                       VerticalOptions="Fill" />
                                    <Label x:Name="Desc" Text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. etc.etc"
                                       Margin="10, -4, 0, 0"
                                       FontSize="15"
                                        FontFamily="Latow"
                                       VerticalOptions="Start"
                                       MaxLines="3"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `Label`'s `BindingContext`

```
private async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var label = (Label)sender;

    // you will need to cast it to the correct type
    var item = (MyClass)label.BindingContext;

    // then pass it to your page
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage(user,item), true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! How can I then extract the title, category and description from the item in my Detailspage, in order to display them there? I have added the xaml code behind the content in my question

Comment: the `item` object should have all the data you need, you just need to set the BindingContext in your new page and use data binding in your XAML

Comment: How do I set the bindingContext in this case? I can't seem to get it work

Comment: `this.BindingContext = TheParameterPassedOnTheConstructor;`